# Hyperledger Composer without npm registry

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Situation:
i'm working with the hyperledger-composer and using the fabric of "fabric-dev-server" BEHIND the proxy in a enterprise-environment without access to the internet!

Question:
How can i managed to work without a npm-Registry (because i did not have one local). I tried out to do some "localhost" -statements in the npmrcFile but this doesn't work.

Is there any chance to Start my business-network ?

thx

Answer (score 1):

node.js chaincode in hyperledger fabric currently needs access to an npm registry when building the chaincode image. As composer utilises node.js chaincode, it is dependent on this access.

The only option you would have is to get an npm registry setup behind your firewall that can be populated with npm modules. Because the dependency tree will be complex, the best way would be to allow the registry access to the internet so that if it doesn't contain an npm module, it can download it from the official npm registry and cache it.

You would then need to point the business network, when you install the business network on your peers, to use that npm registry behind your firewall. You can find more information about this at https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/connector-information where it talks about the `npmrcFile` option.

Comment: hey, step-by-step...:-)

Comment: i just add the proxy and i made a few improvements:

Comment: change the timeout in different files, network with file with a npmrc-file, i checked the proxy via browser and it worked and all i get was this funny message:

Comment: npm ERR! request to https://nexus.ruv.de:8443/repository/npm-all/composer-common failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN nexus.ruv.de:8443

Comment: but: ping is working, wget with the request is working so my question is : what is wrong - which component makes the npm-request ...do i have change something in the peer-container because this is the component which needs access...or

Comment: p.s. my nmprc-File set the registry and sets ssl-strict = false (do i still need the proxy-entries)

Comment: sorry for the unstructured comments but  i'm really disapointed that i need that much time to get my little prototyp working....